# How to dynamically count UBound() values?

Tags: vba, excel

I got something like this:

```
For i = 1 to 4

  cur_tab = "tab_event" & i  

  For e = 1 to Ubound(cur_tab)
    ' do something
  Next

Next
```

I need to dynamically change the cur_tab , but it's not working due to Ubound(cur_tab) is returning a String(e.g.) *Ubound("tab_event1")*

*I've declared all vars and of course I have 'i' tables

"Subscript out of range"

Any ideas ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I'm trying to loop thourgh all tables without having to make a loop for each table, since inside de for code its the same for all tables

Comment: If you are working with tables then why are you using `ubound`? That is used for arrays.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I normally define a table in excel like DIM table1 as variant, and then I do , table1 = Sheets(x).Range(x), can't i do that?

Comment: Yes you can do that but that is not a table per se. You are storing an excel range in a variant array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called `Variable Variables`. It doesn't work like that in VBA. If you have a common procedure then use a separate procedure and use that again and again.

For example, your code can be written as

```
Sub Sample()
    '
    '~~> Rest Of Your Code
    '

    For e = 1 To UBound(tab_event1)
        MySub
    Next

    For e = 1 To UBound(tab_event2)
        MySub
    Next

    For e = 1 To UBound(tab_event3)
        MySub
    Next

    For e = 1 To UBound(tab_event4)
        MySub
    Next

    '
    '~~> Rest Of Your Code
    '
End Sub

Sub MySub()
    MsgBox "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for explanation, I've thought that i could've done that way.